# 'Ungroup method of Range class failed' error

Tags: vba, excel, loops, grouping

I am trying to ungroup and regroup a series of groups I've stored in arrays. When I run it, however, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Ungroup method of Range class failed

My code is below. The `xxxDim` variables are used to identify if an array exists. I have previously identified all the `sSub`, `eSub`, `sGroup`, `eGroup`, `sCat` and `eCat` variables correctly so the actual values are not of concern. I've done the ungrouping and regrouping manually using the exact ranges I refer to so I do not believe I am referring to a range that it is having difficulty figuring out what to ungroup/group.

I have used the ungroup and group methods using this format (`.Range("A" & variable & ":A" & variable).ungroup`) before without issue.

```
''''' START WITH UNGROUPING EVERYTHING '''''
    ''''' SUB-MODELS '''''
    If sSubDim = True Then      'This Array has been dimensioned and therefore has at least one entry
        For i = LBound(sSub) To UBound(sSub)
            .Range("A" & sSub(i) & ":A" & eSub(i)).Ungroup   'Receive error on this line first
        Next
    End If

    ''''' GROUPS '''''
    If sGroupDim = True Then    'Multiple groups exist
        For i = LBound(sGroup) To UBound(sGroup)
            .Range("A" & sGroup(i) & ":A" & eGroup(i)).Ungroup
        Next
    End If

    ''''' CATEGORY '''''
    .Range("A" & sCat & ":A" & eCat).Ungroup


''''' NOW GROUP EVERYTHING '''''
    ''''' SUB-MODELS '''''
    If sSubDim = True Then      'This Array has been dimensioned and therefore has at least one entry
        For i = LBound(sSub) To UBound(sSub)
            .Range("A" & sSub(i) & ":A" & eSub(i)).Group
        Next
    End If

    ''''' GROUPS '''''
    If sGroupDim = True Then    'Multiple groups exist
        For i = LBound(sGroup) To UBound(sGroup)
            .Range("A" & sGroup(i) & ":A" & eGroup(i)).Group
        Next
    End If

    ''''' CATEGORY '''''
    .Range("A" & sCat & ":A" & eCat).Group
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 ''''' START WITH UNGROUPING EVERYTHING '''''
```

Well there's the problem.

Before you can do this:

[image: UNGROUP ALL THE THINGS!]

You need to make sure the *things* are grouped in the first place.

Calling `Range.Ungroup` on cells that aren't grouped, will raise the error you're getting.

I haven't found a way to avoid the error in the 30 seconds I devoted to trying, so a quick-and-dirty work-around would be to wrap the "dangerous" call into its own procedure, and *swallow* any errors that it throws:

```
Private Sub UngroupSafely(ByVal target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    target.Ungroup
    Err.Clear ' Err.Number will be 1004 if target was already ungrouped
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Thus:

```
If sSubDim Then
    For i = LBound(sSub) To UBound(sSub)
        UngroupSafely .Range("A" & sSub(i) & ":A" & eSub(i))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: All my groups I'm ungrouping are definitely grouped already. I ended up changing `.Range("A" & variable & ":A" & variable).ungroup` to `.Rows(variable & ":" & variable).ungroup` and it solved my problem. Not sure why the previous range used works for the section I use it in and not here.

Comment: If they're already grouped, then they will ungroup without a fuss. If you call `.Ungroup` on an ungrouped range, you get exactly the error you're getting. Verify your inputs.